# python-shell and multiprocessing not printing

Tags: python, node.js, ipc, stdout, python-multiprocessing

I have a problem.
I use nodejs's python-shell npm package that allows sending IPC messages to python, and read the python script's print statements as IPC back.

So first I created a fully working python script that accepts stdin and prints to stdout.

Then I implemented the python-shell IPC to send a message to the python script and everything worked.

THE ISSUE began when I created a process in the python script (using multiprocessing.Process), and ported the activity there.

Here I noticed that the newly created processes' stdout isn't received via python-shell! but how is it possible?

Isn't the processes stdout the same as the script running it?

Example, debugable code can be found at the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863360/python-multiprocessing-within-node-js-prints-on-sub-process-not-working) regarding the same issue.

Please - any lead may help.

Answer (score 0):

May be the same thing I am doing currently. You can use PythonShell. Lets see a example then you can understand.

```
var myPythonScriptPath = 'script.py';

// Use python shell
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
var pyshell = new PythonShell(myPythonScriptPath);

pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
// received a message sent from the Python script (a simple "print" statement)
console.log(message);
});

// end the input stream and allow the process to exit
pyshell.end(function (err) {
if (err){
    throw err;
};

console.log('finished');
});
```

Lete me know if you still have problem. Happy coding.

Comment: Same thing I was doing

Comment: then what is the problem ?

Comment: python prints() from a multiprocessing.Process process aren't caught by pyshell.on()

Comment: I am also doing multi processing. Do you use child_process ?